# Serialize / Deserialize a struct that can be represented as an array of bytes

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

I am working with a `struct` that looks more or less like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
   // Various fields, most of which do not implement `Serialize` / `Deserialize`
}

struct MyError; // Yes, this implements `std::error::Error`

impl MyStruct {
   fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; 96]) -> Result<MyStruct, MyError> {
      // Creates a `MyStruct` from an array of exactly 96 bytes.
      // It returns a `MyError` upon failure.
   }

   fn to_bytes(&self) -> [u8; 96] {
      // Serializes `MyStruct` into an array of exactly 96 bytes.
   }
}
```

Now, I would like to have `MyStruct` implement `serde`'s `Serialize` and `Deserialize`. Intuition tells me it should be simple (I literally have functions that already serialize and deserialize `MyStruct`), but after hours of confused trial and error I'm stuck.

What I would like to have is `MyStruct` implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` and, should I call `bincode::serialize(my_struct)`, I would like it to be represented in exactly 96 bytes (i.e., I would like to avoid paying the cost of a pointless, 8-byte header that always says "what follows is a sequence of 96 bytes": I already know that I need 96 bytes to represent `MyStruct`!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of your question can be accomplished as following:

```rust
use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};
use serde_big_array::BigArray;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Wrap {
    #[serde(with = "BigArray")]
    arr: [u8; 96],
}

struct MyStruct {}

struct MyError;

impl Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; 96]) -> Result<MyStruct, MyError> {
        todo!()
    }

    fn to_bytes(&self) -> [u8; 96] {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl serde::Serialize for MyStruct {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        Wrap {
            arr: self.to_bytes(),
        }
        .serialize(serializer)
    }
}

impl<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de> for MyStruct {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let bytes = <Wrap>::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Self::from_bytes(bytes.arr).map_err(D::Error::custom)
    }
}
```

The second part is tough and depends on the format you are using with serde.